# Is it possible to add a WSGIRequest to a Django model?

Tags: python, django, models, django-wsgi

I'd like to save a WSGIRequest to a Django model to do some debugging.  Is it possible to create a model to do this?  I get all kinds of errors when I try:

```
class MyRequest(models.Model):
    request = WSGIRequest()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you expect to be able to persist an object with all kinds of ephermal state to the database?

Comment: It is definitely not a good idea. If you persist _every_ request, you could run into scale issues too, as you would be doing multiple writes unnecessarily. For debugging, you the stacktrace is sufficient in most of the cases. You can configure to get emails on error: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/error-reporting/ .

Answer (score 0):

Why would you expect to be able to persist an object with all kinds of ephermal state to the database?

You best bet is probably to write a function that takes a Request object, pulls out whatever information is relevant to you and creates a string with the info in persist that.

Doing a json.dumps on the whole object  work.